# Are there historical texts recording acts of ransom / heists on the rich in Roman Empire?

Tags: roman-empire

I know that large scale slave revolts in Roman Empire were relatively rare.

On smaller scales though, in modern times we have house invasions / kidnapping and car theft.

In Rome with gap being so wide are there accounts of say crime against the rich or where the punishments so harsh it didn’t happen?

Comment: Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions. Please revise your question to document your preliminary research.

Comment: Well Caesar was kidnapped and ransomed by pirates,  they were crucified later.  Crassus hired fire crews that would set fires, then go to property owners near the property and extort them (with a super low valuation,) once sold his crews would put out the fire and profit.  Also the proscription lists from Sulla and Augustus/Antony are pretty close to a heist, wrapped in a veneer of legality, that usually ended in murder.

Comment: Julius Caesar was famously kidnapped by pirates. He mocked them for asking too small a ransom, and publicly vowed to return and apprehend them; which he followed through with.